QGIS - Using non-basic authentication for vector data layer not possible
In QGIS I added OAuth and HTTP header authentication. When adding a new layer, I can use those methods for e.g. WFS and WMS. Unfortunately, when adding a vector layer via HTTP, I can only use basic authentication. How can I use OAuth and HTTP header authentication methods for vector layers retrieved via HTTP?



Tested in QGIS 3.28.11 and 3.4.13
